# Using Delphi LockBox 3: How to communicate with android device?

Tags: android, delphi, aes, delphi-xe8, lockbox-3

I'm building a RESTful server using Delphi XE8 with LockBox 3 for encryption. I use AES to encrypt data (JSON) and send it to an Adroid device - Client.

If I send the encrypted data to client and the client knows the encryption key, how could he decrypt the data without knowing the IV because it auto managed by LB3 internally?

**I'm using Delphi XE8**

First: I installed LockBox last version.

Second: there is no documentation on how to set the IV.

I managed to get the IV (first 8 bytes from ciphertext):

```
function TAESEnrypt.EncryptAES_String(const str: string): string;
var
 Codec1: TCodec;
 CryptographicLibrary1: TCryptographicLibrary;
 bt:TByteArray;
 m:TMemoryStream;
 AEncoding: TEncoding;
 pCipher: TBytes;
 bytes: TBytes;
 text: string;
 Encoding: TEncoding;
 iv:TBytes;
 cipher:TBytes;
 i:integer;
begin
  Result:='';
  KeyHex:='';
  KeyBin:=TMemoryStream.Create;
  Codec1 := TCodec.Create( nil);
  CryptographicLibrary1 := TCryptographicLibrary.Create( nil);
  Codec1.CryptoLibrary  := CryptographicLibrary1;
  Codec1.StreamCipherId := BlockCipher_ProgId;
  Codec1.BlockCipherId  := 'native.AES-128';
  Codec1.ChainModeId    := CBC_ProgId;
  Codec1.Password := Password;
  Codec1.EncryptString(str, CipherText, TEncoding.UTF8);
  Result:=CipherText;
  Codec1.Key.SaveToStream(KeyBin);
  Codec1.Free;
  CryptographicLibrary1.Free;
  //key ==> HEX
  KeyBin.Position:=0;
  SetLength(KeyHex,KeyBin.Size*2);
  SetLength(bt, KeyBin.Size);
  KeyBin.Read(bt[0],KeyBin.Size);
  KeyBin.Position:=0;
  BinToHex(bt[0],pchar(KeyHex),KeyBin.Size);
  //key ==> base64
  Key64:=TNetEncoding.Base64.EncodeBytesToString(bt);
  //
  {
   Ciphertext = Base64
   IV ==> Extract the first 8 bytes (64 bits)
   1. Base64 ==> Binary
   2. get IV
   3. Binary ==> Base64 (Ciphertext)
   4. Binary ==> Base64 (IV)
   5. Binary ==> HEX (Ciphertext)
   6. Binary ==> HEX (IV)
  }
  bytes := TNetEncoding.Base64.DecodeStringToBytes(CipherText);//result => binary data
  iv:=Copy(bytes,0,8);//get first 8 bytes (iv) => binary data
  cipher:=Copy(bytes,8,Length(bytes)-8);//the rest is the encrypted data => binary data
  //Bin => base64
  iv64:=TNetEncoding.Base64.EncodeBytesToString(iv);
  cipher64:=TNetEncoding.Base64.EncodeBytesToString(cipher);
  //Bin => HEX
  SetLength(ivHex,Length(iv)*2);
  BinToHex(iv[0],pchar(ivHex),Length(iv));
  SetLength(CipherHex,Length(cipher));
  BinToHex(Cipher[0],pchar(CipherHex),Length(Cipher));
end;
```

For example (128):

```
iv_64 : P7NJIfhws2k=
iv_hex: 3FB34921F870B369
cipher_64 : 5UvFMw==
cipher_hex: E54B
Key_64 : /dn9yyUOTWobOQx1A+ZfAg==
Key_hex: FDD9FDCB250E4D6A1B390C7503E65F02
```

On the client side (Android) I get the error "Bad base 64" or "last block incomplete in decryption" and here is my code (it's only for testing):

[I complete the IV with zeros]

```
            byte[] out=new byte[16];
            byte[] zero="00000000".getBytes();

            byte[] ivBytes; byte[] keyBytes; byte[] textBytes;
            ivBytes=Base64.decode("9pdfnd4JvpI=".getBytes("UTF-8"),Base64.DEFAULT);
            System.arraycopy(ivBytes,0,out,0,ivBytes.length);
            System.arraycopy(zero,0,out,ivBytes.length,zero.length);

            keyBytes=Base64.decode("/dn9yyUOTWobOQx1A+ZfAg==".getBytes("UTF-8"),Base64.DEFAULT);
            textBytes=Base64.decode("+JnDcw==".getBytes("UTF-8"),Base64.DEFAULT);
            AlgorithmParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(out);
            SecretKeySpec newKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NOPADDING");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, newKey,ivSpec);
            byte[] decodedBytes = cipher.doFinal(textBytes);
            String plain=new String(decodedBytes,"UTF-8");
```

When I run this in Android I get: "last block incomplete in decryption" and when I remove the "UTF-8" from getBytes() I get "bad base-64", and I don't know how to solve it, any idea?

Comment: As I understand from [AES Encrypt/Decrypt Delphi & PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12138580/576719), the IV is prepended in the message from the server.

Comment: Interesting....

Comment: LU RD is correct. Just to add a little more detail: The low 8 bytes of the IV is the first 8 bytes of the output. If your block size is greater than 8 bytes, the high bytes of the IV are zero.

Comment: P.S. I'm working on the next version of Lockbox, where you will be able to explicitly specify your own IV.

Comment: It's almost ready. I am just upgrading the suite of unit tests to a new unit testing framework - dunit-m.

Comment: ... And it's done. Locate version 3.7.0 at https://github.com/SeanBDurkin/tplockbox

Comment: I've edited your answer into the question. You can use the [edit] link below your post for updates. Your question now shows effort, so I'm giving you an upvote. Hope you'll be able to figure it out.