# TPLockBox3 and PHP - AES Encrypt in Delphi, Decrypt in PHP

Tags: php, delphi, cryptography, aes, lockbox-3

I have a trouble with lockbox3 and PHP mcrypt. I can't pass IV to PHP. [Delphi code](http://pastebin.com/pyCCmqcm):

```
var
  Codec: TCodec;
  CL: TCryptographicLibrary;
  PlainStream: TStringStream;
  CipherStream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  PlainStream := TStringStream.Create(Edit1.Text);
  CipherStream := TMemoryStream.Create;

  CL := TCryptographicLibrary.Create(nil);
  Codec := TCodec.Create(nil);
  Codec.CryptoLibrary := CL;
  Codec.ChainModeId := uTPLb_Constants.CBC_ProgId;
  Codec.StreamCipherId := uTPLb_Constants.BlockCipher_ProgId;
  Codec.BlockCipherId := Format(uTPLb_Constants.AES_ProgId, [256]);
  Codec.Password := Edit3.Text;

  Codec.EncryptStream(PlainStream, CipherStream);
  Codec.Burn;

  Memo1.Text := Stream_to_Base64(CipherStream);
  Memo2.Clear;
  Memo2.Lines.Add(Format('Size: %d bytes', [CipherStream.Size]));
  Memo2.Lines.Add(Format('Original size: %d bytes', [PlainStream.Size]));

  Codec.Free;
  CL.Free;
  CipherStream.Free;
  PlainStream.Free;
```

And [PHP code](http://pastebin.com/SSV4T36c):

```
  $ciphertext = base64_decode("zA/eeF+WFVMDsZ7+iA==");
  $iv = substr($ciphertext, 0, 8);
  $text = substr($ciphertext, 8, strlen($ciphertext) - 8);

  $td = mcrypt_module_open("rijndael-256", "", "cbc", $iv);
  mcrypt_generic_init($td, "PasswordPassword", $iv);
  $plaintext = mdecrypt_generic($td, $text);
  echo $plaintext;
  mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
  mcrypt_module_close($td);
```

I got an error:

> Warning: mcrypt_generic_init() [function.mcrypt-generic-init]: Iv size incorrect; supplied length: 8, needed: 32 in C:...\aestest.php on line 7

Related thread: [AES Encrypt/Decrypt Delphi & PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12138244/aes-encrypt-decrypt-delphi-php)

Comment: `rijndael-256` is not AES. Use rijndael-128 instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't said what version of Delphi you are using. This is an important detail. For the moment, I will assume it is Delphi 2010. There are a number of problems with your code. I will  address them...

(1) In Delphi 2010 and later, strings are encoded in UTF-16LE, whilst in PHP, strings are UTF-8. Consider this line of yours...

```
PlainStream := TStringStream.Create(Edit1.Text);
```

What you are doing is creating the UTF-16LE encoding of your payload string. You encrypt this and pass it over to the PHP side and decrypt it. But you are not going to get the expected result because the decrypted bytes are UTF-16LE, but PHP expects them to be UTF-8.

(2) TP Lockbox 3 already had native methods for encrypting strings. Why not use them?

(3) The block size for all 3 variations of AES is 128 bits, which is 16 bytes. The size of the IV is **always** the size of the block. On the PHP side, as a matter of generic coding, you should always call  [mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-enc-get-iv-size.php) (you did not). Please read the [reference page here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-generic-init.php). In any case, for AES-256 must return 16 bytes. If not something is seriously wrong.

(4) Your passwords are not the same, so you can never reasonably expect a happy result. On the Delphi side, your password is encoded in UTF-16LE. On the PHP side, your password is the UTF-8 encoding of 'PasswordPassword', which can never be byte-for-byte equal to something valid in UTF-16.

(5) On the PHP side, you wrote..

```
 $iv = substr($ciphertext, 0, 8);
```

You need to zero-extend this out to 16 bytes. Refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328320).

---

## UPDATE

As promised, here is some PHP code to decrypt ciphertext messages produced by TurboPower LockBox 3. You will need to craft a css file, otherwise presentation will be ugly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="CONTENT-TYPE" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW,NOARCHIVE" />
    <META NAME="DESCRIPTION" CONTENT="Tutorial and demostration page for Delphi (TurboPower LockBox3) to PHP symetric cryptography." />
    <META NAME="AUTHOR" CONTENT="Sean B. Durkin">
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
    <META NAME="KEYWORDS" CONTENT="cryptography,delphi,php,turbopower,lockbox,lockbox3">
    <title>Delphi-to-PHP Cryptography Tutorial</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-device-width:  721px)" href="tut.css" /><!-- <== Desktop. -->     
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-device-width:  720px)" href="tut-phone.css" / --><!-- <== Phone and tablet. -->  
 <head>

<body>
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_COMPILE_ERROR);
$password = $_GET["password"];
$ciphertext_trans = $_GET["ciphertext-trans"];
$rawInputCiphertext = $_GET["ciphertext"];
$chain = $_GET["chain"];
$cipherIn = $_GET["cipherIn"];

function radioChecked($param,$value,$isDefault)
{
  $echo = (($param == $value) or ($isDefault and ($param == ''))) ? ' checked="checked" ' : '';
  echo $echo;
  return $echo != '';  
}
?>

<nav>
  <div class="nav-bg"></div>
  <div class="nav-content">
    <h1><a href="http://lockbox.seanbdurkin.id.au/tiki-index.php?page=Delphi-to-PHP+Tutorial+project+home" title="Go to The Delphi-to-PHP project home"><span class="hidden">Project home</span></a></h1>
    <dl>
      <dt>Date created</dt>
      <dd><time datetime="2012-11-29">29-Nov-2012</time></dd>
    </dl>
    <dl>
      <dt>Date last modified</dt>
      <dd><time datetime="2012-12-02">2-Dec-2012</time></dd>
    </dl>
  </div>    
</nav>

<h1>Decrypt with PHP from Delphi (TurboPower LockBox3)</h1>
<form id="plainForm" class="floatbox" action="">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Crypto data</legend>
    <label class="first" for="password">Password (UTF-8)
      <input id="password" name="password" type="text" placeholder="Enter TCodec password" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($password) ?>" />
    </label>            
    <fieldset class="radio">
      <legend>Transport encoding</legend>
        <label for="ciphertext-trans-base64">
          <input id="ciphertext-trans-base64" name="ciphertext-trans" type="radio" value="base64" 
          <?php radioChecked($ciphertext_trans,'base64',True); ?> />base64
        </label>
        <label for="ciphertext-trans-hex">
          <input id="ciphertext-trans-hex" name="ciphertext-trans" type="radio" value="hex" 
          <?php radioChecked($ciphertext_trans,'hex',False); ?> />hex
        </label>
    </fieldset>             
    <label for="ciphertext">Ciphertext (transport encoded)
      <input id="ciphertext" name="ciphertext" type="text" placeholder="Paste ciphertext here" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($rawInputCiphertext) ?>" />
    </label>            
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Options</legend>
    <fieldset class="radio">
      <legend>Chaining mode</legend>
        <label for="chain-cfb">
          <input id="chain-cfb" name="chain" type="radio" 
            value="CFB" <?php radioChecked($chain,'CFB',True); ?> />CFB
        </label>
        <label for="chain-cbc">
          <input id="chain-cbc" name="chain" type="radio"
            value="CBC" <?php radioChecked($chain,'CBC',False); ?> />CBC
        </label>
        <label for="chain-ecb">
          <input id="chain-ecb" name="chain" type="radio"
            value="ECB" <?php radioChecked($chain,'ECB',False); ?> />ECB
        </label>
    </fieldset>             

    <fieldset class="radio">
      <legend>Cipher</legend>
        <label for="aes-128">
          <input id="aes-128" name="cipherIn" type="radio" 
            value="AES-128" <?php radioChecked($cipherIn,'AES-128',True); ?> />AES-128
        </label>
        <!-- Extend here with more ciphers as required. Note: PHP does not support AES-256. -->
    </fieldset>             

    </fieldset>             
  <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Decrypt" />
</form>
<?php if ($chain) { ?>
<?php
function purgeWhiteSpace($sparseHex)
{
    return preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $sparseHex);
}
function expandWithWhiteSpace($compactHex)
{
// TODO: Insert white space for visual benefit. Bunch the brown spaces
//  into words of 6 characters, and then separate words with a single space.
//  Between every 10th word and 11th word, use a new-line ($0D) instead of space.
//  Assume that $compactHex ONLY consists of characters 0..9 and A..F .
    return $compactHex;
}
function displayableMultiline($str)
{
// TODO: Assume $str ONLY consists of characters whose code-points are below
//  137. Insert '<br />' before each $0D character.
    return $str;
}
function hexToStr($hex)
{
    $hex2 = purgeWhiteSpace( $hex);
    $str='';
    for ($i=0; $i < strlen($hex2)-1; $i+=2)
    {
        $str .= chr(hexdec($hex2[$i].$hex2[$i+1]));
    }
    return $str;
}   
function strToHex($str)
{
    $hex='';
    for ($i=0; $i < strlen($str); $i++)
    {       
        $addend = dechex(ord($str[$i]));
        if (strlen($addend) < 2)
          $addend = '0' . $addend;
        $hex .= $addend;
    }
    return $hex;
}

$normalisedRawCiphertext = purgeWhiteSpace( $rawInputCiphertext);
if ($ciphertext_trans == 'base64')
{ 
  $ciphertext = base64_decode( $normalisedRawCiphertext);
}
else
{
  $ciphertext = hexToStr( $normalisedRawCiphertext);
}

if ($cipherIn == 'AES-128')
{
  $cipher = MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128;
  $cipherName = 'AES-128';
}
else
{
  // Extend here with more ciphers as required. Note: PHP does not support AES-256.
  $cipher = MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128; // Example only.
  $cipherName = '???';           // Example only.
}

if ($chain == 'CFB')
    $mode = 'ncfb';  // Proper block-mode CFB. There is no constant for this.
  else if ($chain == 'CBC') 
    $mode = MCRYPT_MODE_CBC;
  else  
    $mode = MCRYPT_MODE_ECB;

$blockSize = mcrypt_get_block_size( $cipher, $mode);
$keySize = mcrypt_get_key_size( $cipher, $mode);

// Work-around PHP bugs.
if (($cipher == MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128) and ($keySize == 32))
  { $keySize = 16; }   // AES-128 key size is 16 bytes.
if (($cipher == MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256) and ($blockSize == 32))
  { $blockSize = 16; } // AES-256 block size is 16 bytes.

$ivSize = $blockSize; // Always. mcrypt_get_iv_size() is pointless.

if ($chain == 'ECB')
{
    $iv = str_pad( 'NOT USED', 16, chr(0));
    // $ciphertext unchanged.
}
else
{
    $iv = substr( $ciphertext, 0, 8);
    $iv = str_pad( $iv, $ivSize, chr(0));
    $ciphertext = substr( $ciphertext, 8);
}

$ciphertextLen = strlen( $ciphertext);
if  (($ciphertextLen > 0) && ($ciphertextLen < $blockSize) && ($chain == 'CBC'))
 { $mode = MCRYPT_MODE_CFB; } // CFB 8-bit. This is NOT the same as CFB.

if (strlen($password)==$keySize)
  {
    $key = $password;
  }
else
  {
    $shaPassword = sha1( $password, True);
    for ($key = ''; strlen( $key) < $keySize; $key .= $shaPassword) {}
    $key = substr( $key, 0, $keySize);
  }  

$countBlocks = $ciphertextLen / $blockSize;
$countWholeBlocks = floor( $countBlocks); 
$isRound = $countBlocks == $countWholeBlocks; 
if ($isRound)
    {
    $lastBlockSize = 0;
    }
  else
    {
    $countBlocks = $countWholeBlocks + 1;
    $lastBlockSize = $ciphertextLen - ($countWholeBlocks * $blockSize);
    }     
$isCipherStealing = ($mode == MCRYPT_MODE_CBC) && ($countWholeBlocks >= 1) && !$isRound;
if ($isCipherStealing)
    { // Reverse ciphertext stealing.
/* 
Ciphertext stealing algorithm - Encryption:
  Mix     := Enc( CV[N-2], X[N-2]);
  Steal   := Last( B-b, Mix);
  Recycle := X[N-1] + Steal;
  Y[N-2]  := Enc( CV[N-2], Recycle);
  Y[N-1]  := Head( b, Mix);

Ciphertext stealing algorithm - Decryption:
  Recycle := Dec( CV[N-2], Y[N-2]);
  Steal   := Last( B-b, Recycle);
  Mix     := Y[N-1] + Steal;
  X[N-2]  := Dec( CV[N-2], Mix);
  X[N-1]  := Head( b, Recycle);  
*/  
    // 1. Recycle := Dec( CV[N-2], Y[N-2]);
    $Recycle = mcrypt_decrypt ( $cipher, $key, substr( $ciphertext, 0, $countWholeBlocks * $blockSize), $mode, $iv);
    $reconUpToX_N_3 = substr( $Recycle, 0, ($countWholeBlocks - 1) * $blockSize); // X[0]..X{N-3]
    $Recycle = substr( $Recycle, ($countWholeBlocks - 1) * $blockSize, $blockSize);

    // 2. Steal := Last( B-b, Recycle);
    $Steal = substr( $Recycle, $lastBlockSize, $blockSize - $lastBlockSize);

    // 3. Mix := Y[N-1] + Steal;
    $Y_N1 = substr( $ciphertext, $countWholeBlocks * $blockSize, $lastBlockSize);
    $Mix = $Y_N1 . $Steal;

    // 4. X[N-2]  := Dec( CV[N-2], Mix);
    $reconUpToX_N_2 = mcrypt_decrypt ( $cipher, $key, substr( $ciphertext, 0, ($countWholeBlocks - 1) * $blockSize) . $Mix, $mode, $iv);

    // 5. X[N-1] := Head( b, Recycle);
    $reconX_N_1 = substr( $Recycle, 0, $lastBlockSize);

    // Putting it alltogether.
    $recon = $reconUpToX_N_2 . $reconX_N_1;
    }
  else
    { // Normal decyrption.
    $recon = mcrypt_decrypt ( $cipher, $key, $ciphertext, $mode, $iv);
    }
if (($chain == 'ECB') and ($recon != ''))
  { // Trim ECB padding.
  $last = strlen($recon);
  for ($l = strlen($recon); ($l >= 0) and (ord($recon[$l])==0); $l--)
    {$last = $l;}
  $recon = substr( $recon, 0, $last-1);
  }
?>
<hr />
<h2>Output</h2>
<h3>Summary2</h3>
<p>Cipher is <em><?php echo $cipherName; ?></em></p>
<p>Block size is <?php echo $blockSize; ?> bytes</p>
<?php if ($isRound) { ?>
  <p>Given ciphertext was a round <?php echo $countBlocks; ?> blocks long.</p>
<?php } else { ?>
  <p>Given ciphertext was a <?php echo $countWholeBlocks; ?> whole blocks long and <?php echo $lastBlockSize; ?> bytes in an odd block.</p>
<?php } ?>
<p>Key size is <?php echo $keySize; ?> bytes</p>
<p>Given chain mode was <em><?php echo $chain; ?></em></p>
<p>Given password was <em>&apos;<?php echo htmlspecialchars($password); ?>&apos;</em></p>
<p>Ciphertext as hex is...</p>
<code><?php echo '[' . $ciphertextLen . '] ' . displayableMultiline( expandWithWhiteSpace( strToHex( $ciphertext))); ?></code>
<p></p>
<p>Reconstructed plaintext message is <em>&apos;<?php echo htmlspecialchars( $recon); ?>&apos;</em></p>
<p></p>
<h2>Debug</h2>
<p>Key as hex is...</p>
<code><?php echo '[' . strlen($key) . '] ' . expandWithWhiteSpace( strToHex( $key)); ?></code>
<p>IV as hex is...</p>
<code><?php echo '[' . strlen($iv) . '] ' . expandWithWhiteSpace( strToHex( $iv)); ?></code>
<p>$countBlocks = <code><?php echo $countBlocks; ?></code></p>
<p>$countWholeBlocks = <code><?php echo $countWholeBlocks; ?></code></p>
<p>$isRound = <code><?php echo $isRound ? 'True' : 'False'; ?></code></p>
<p>$isCipherStealing = <code><?php echo $isCipherStealing ? 'True' : 'False'; ?></code></p>
<p>$lastBlockSize = <code><?php echo $lastBlockSize; ?></code></p>
<p>$Recycle = <code><?php echo '[' . strlen($Recycle) . '] ' . strToHex( $Recycle); ?></code></p>
<p>$recon X[0..N-3] = <code><?php echo '[' . strlen($reconUpToX_N_3) . '] ' . strToHex( $reconUpToX_N_3); ?></code></p>
<p>$Steal = <code><?php echo '[' . strlen($Steal) . '] ' . strToHex( $Steal); ?></code></p>
<p>$Mix = <code><?php echo '[' . strlen($Mix) . '] ' . strToHex( $Mix); ?></code></p>
<p>$recon X[0..N-2] = <code><?php echo '[' . strlen($reconUpToX_N_2) . '] ' . strToHex( $reconUpToX_N_2); ?></code></p>
<p>$recon X[N-1] = <code><?php echo '[' . strlen($reconX_N_1) . '] ' . strToHex( $reconX_N_1); ?></code></p>
<p>Reconstructed plaintext as hex is...</p>
<code><?php echo '[' . strlen($recon) . '] ' . expandWithWhiteSpace( strToHex( $recon)); ?></code>
<?php } ?>
</body> 
</html>
```

**... and here is a matching Delphi program to produce the ciphertext messages for the preceding PHP web page, for test and demonstration purposes. (DFM file not included)...**

```
unit umfmDelphi_to_PHP_Symetric;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, ActnList, StdCtrls, uTPLb_Codec, uTPLb_BaseNonVisualComponent,
  uTPLb_CryptographicLibrary, ExtCtrls;

type
  TmfmDelphi_to_PHP_Symetric = class(TForm)
    rgTestVectors: TRadioGroup;
    rgChainMode: TRadioGroup;
    edtPassword: TEdit;
    memoPlaintext: TMemo;
    lblPassword: TLabel;
    lblPlaintext: TLabel;
    cryptoMain: TCryptographicLibrary;
    codecAES: TCodec;
    memoOutput: TMemo;
    btnEncrypt: TButton;
    actlstMain: TActionList;
    actEncrypt: TAction;
    edtSeed: TEdit;
    lblSeed: TLabel;
    btnRandomize: TButton;
    actRandomize: TAction;
    rgCipher: TRadioGroup;
    procedure actEncryptUpdate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure actEncryptExecute(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure rgTestVectorsClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure rgChainModeClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure actRandomizeUpdate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure actRandomizeExecute(Sender: TObject);

  private
    procedure LogFmt( const sLine: string; const Args: array of const);
    function  SpaceOut( const sCompacted: string): string;

  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  mfmDelphi_to_PHP_Symetric: TmfmDelphi_to_PHP_Symetric;

implementation



uses uTPLb_Random, uTPLb_StreamUtils, uTPLb_Constants;

{$R *.dfm}


function StreamToHex( Data: TStream): string;
var
  b: byte;
  sByte: string;
begin
Data.Position := 0;
result := '';
while Data.Read( b, 1) = 1 do
  begin
  sByte := Format( '%x', [b]);
  if Odd( Length( sByte)) then
    sByte := '0' + sByte;
  result := result + sByte
  end
end;


procedure TmfmDelphi_to_PHP_Symetric.actEncryptExecute( Sender: TObject);
const
  TestCaseNames: array[0..2] of string = ('Test Vector 1', 'Test Vector 2', 'Custom');
var
  usPlaintext: UTF8String;
  aCiphertext: ansistring;
  OriginalSeed: int64;
  stmCipher: TStream;
  sHex: string;
begin
memoOutput.Clear;
case rgCipher.ItemIndex of
  0:   codecAES.BlockCipherId := Format( AES_ProgId, [128]);
end;
case rgChainMode.ItemIndex of
  0:   codecAES.ChainModeId := CFB_ProgId;
  1:   codecAES.ChainModeId := CBC_ProgId;
  2:   codecAES.ChainModeId := ECB_ProgId;
  end;
codecAES.UTF8Password := edtPassword.Text;
usPlaintext := memoPlaintext.Lines.Text;
OriginalSeed := StrToInt64( edtSeed.Text);
TRandomStream.Instance.Seed := OriginalSeed;
codecAES.EncryptAnsiString( usPlaintext, aCiphertext);
// NextSeed := TRandomStream.Instance.Seed;
LogFmt( 'Test case = %s', [TestCaseNames[rgTestVectors.ItemIndex]]);
LogFmt( 'Cipher = %s', [codecAES.Cipher]);
LogFmt( 'Chain mode = %s', [codecAES.ChainMode]);
LogFmt( 'PRNG seed = %d', [OriginalSeed]);
LogFmt( 'Passord (UTF-8) = ''%s''', [codecAES.UTF8Password]);

LogFmt( '------------', []);
stmCipher := TMemoryStream.Create;
codecAES.Key.SaveToStream( stmCipher);
sHex := StreamToHex( stmCipher);
stmCipher.Free;
LogFmt( 'key as hex = %s', [sHex]);
LogFmt( 'Plaintext (UTF-8)', []);
LogFmt( '''%s''', [usPlaintext]);
LogFmt( '------------', []);
LogFmt( 'ciphertext (base64) [Includes prepended IV and block quantisation] =', []);
LogFmt( ' ''%s''', [ SpaceOut( aCiphertext)]);
LogFmt( '------------', []);
stmCipher := TMemoryStream.Create;
Base64_to_stream( aCiphertext, stmCipher);
sHex := StreamToHex( stmCipher);
stmCipher.Free;
LogFmt( 'ciphertext (hex) [Includes prepended IV and block quantisation] =', []);
LogFmt( ' ''%s''', [ SpaceOut( sHex)]);
LogFmt( '------------', []);
end;

procedure TmfmDelphi_to_PHP_Symetric.actEncryptUpdate( Sender: TObject);
begin
//
end;

procedure TmfmDelphi_to_PHP_Symetric.actRandomizeExecute(Sender: TObject);
begin
TRandomStream.Instance.Randomize;
edtSeed.Text := IntToStr( TRandomStream.Instance.Seed)
end;

procedure TmfmDelphi_to_PHP_Symetric.actRandomizeUpdate(Sender: TObject);
begin
(Sender as TAction).Enabled := rgTestVectors.ItemIndex = 2
end;

procedure TmfmDelphi_to_PHP_Symetric.FormCreate( Sender: TObject);
begin
memoOutput.Clear;
LogFmt( 'Select test case and chain mode.', []);
LogFmt( 'Enter password and plaintext message and then press the ''Encrypt'' button.', []);
end;

procedure TmfmDelphi_to_PHP_Symetric.LogFmt(
  const sLine: string; const Args: array of const);
begin
memoOutput.Lines.Add( Format( sLine, Args))
end;

procedure TmfmDelphi_to_PHP_Symetric.rgChainModeClick( Sender: TObject);
begin
//
end;

procedure TmfmDelphi_to_PHP_Symetric.rgTestVectorsClick( Sender: TObject);
var
  isCustom: boolean;
begin
case rgTestVectors.ItemIndex of
  0:   begin
       edtPassword.Text := 'Your lips are smoother than vasoline.';
       memoPlaintext.Lines.Text := 'Leeeeeeeeeroy Jenkins!';
         // Above is constrained to:
         //  More than 16 and not a whole multiple of 16 bytes as UTF-8.
       edtSeed.Text := '1';
       rgChainMode.ItemIndex := 0;
       rgCipher.ItemIndex := 0;
       end;
  1:   begin
       edtPassword.Text := 'ORATIO IN L. CATILINAM PRIMA';
       memoPlaintext.Lines.Text := 'Quo usque tandem abutere, Catili';
         // Above is constrained to:
         //  A whole multiple of 16 bytes as UTF-8, excluding the empty case.
       edtSeed.Text := '333';
       rgChainMode.ItemIndex := 0;
       rgCipher.ItemIndex := 0
       end;
  2:   ;
  end;
isCustom := rgTestVectors.ItemIndex = 2;
edtPassword.ReadOnly := not isCustom;
memoPlaintext.ReadOnly := not isCustom;
edtSeed.ReadOnly := not isCustom;
rgChainMode.Enabled := isCustom;
rgCipher.Enabled := isCustom
end;

function TmfmDelphi_to_PHP_Symetric.SpaceOut( const sCompacted: string): string;
const
  NewLineSpacing = 70;
  BunchSpacing = 6;
var
  i, j: integer;
begin
SetLength( result, 2 * Length( sCompacted));
i := 1;
for j := 1 to Length( sCompacted) do
  begin
  if ((j mod NewLineSpacing) = 1) and (j <> 1) then
      begin
      result[i] := #13;
      Inc( i);
      result[i] := #10;
      Inc( i)
      end
    else if ((j mod BunchSpacing) = 1) and (j <> 1) then
      begin
      result[i] := ' ';
      Inc( i)
      end;
  result[i] := sCompacted[j];
  Inc( i)
  end;
SetLength( result, i - 1)
end;

end.
```

Comment: Yes, you were right with assuming version of Delphi as D2010.

`$td = mcrypt_module_open("rijndael-256", "", "cbc", "");
$ivsize = mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($td);
echo "IV size: $ivsize";`

This code prints: `IV size: 32`

Comment: The IV and block size for AES is 16 bytes. The key size for AES-256 is 32 bytes. This is in the standard and can't be changed. If your implementation says otherwise, then your implementation is not conformant to the AES standard.

Comment: But PHP tells me that IV size is 32 bytes

Comment: You can find the spec [here](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips197/fips-197.pdf). The block size is on page 1. If PHP is wrong, then you need to take that up with the PHP vendors.

Comment: Passing `iconv("UTF-8", "UTF-16LE", "PasswordPassword")` as key give no effect in php. IV is padded with zeros (`chr(0)`) to `$ivlen`

Comment: Also note [here](http://drupal.org/node/1107062) and [here](http://www.ilovemyjournal.com/?action=view_entry&eid=4638). It's a bug in PHP.

Comment: Thank you for you message. Someone commented at another site:


"You would think that MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 specifies 256-bit encryption, but that is wrong. The three choices specify the block-size to be used with Rijndael encryption."
 From http://www.chilkatsoft.com/p/php_aes.asp

Comment: I don't understand how to pass password in correct encoding. Use `AnsiString` in Delphi? Or use encoding conversion functions in PHP?

Comment: If you can wait a few days, some working PHP code will be posted.