# What happened to UTF8Password in LockBox 3's TCodec?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7, lockbox-3

I have been following the Delphi code in [TPLockBox3 and PHP - AES Encrypt in Delphi, Decrypt in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13534360/tplockbox3-and-php-aes-encrypt-in-delphi-decrypt-in-php),
but I cannot implement Sean's: "codecAES.UTF8Password := edtPassword.Text;" within his actEncryptExecute procedure as this class does not have this property.

Answer (score 1):

Sean's answer is based on his new LockBox fork. You can find it under Google Code:

https://code.google.com/p/tplockbox/

If you check out this fork you will see that there is a UTF8Password property.